# Не определяется монитор подключеннй по HDMI к ноуту с ОС Linux Mint

Tags: linux, администрирование, linux-mint

Пытаюсь подключить монитор к ноуту, но он почему-то не определяется. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.
Выхлоп "inxi -Frz":

```
System:    Kernel: 5.10.0-1013-oem x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Cinnamon 4.8.6 Distro: Linux Mint 20.1 Ulyssa 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: HP product: HP ZBook Firefly 15 G7 Mobile Workstation v: N/A serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: HP model: 8724 v: KBC Version 06.34.00 serial: <filter> UEFI: HP v: S73 Ver. 01.01.07 date: 08/24/2020 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT0 charge: 55.2 Wh condition: 55.2/56.3 Wh (98%) 
CPU:       Topology: Quad Core model: Intel Core i7-10510U bits: 64 type: MT MCP L2 cache: 8192 KiB 
           Speed: 1991 MHz min/max: 400/4900 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 745 2: 773 3: 905 4: 773 5: 858 6: 828 7: 941 8: 819 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics driver: i915 v: kernel 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics (CML GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.2.6 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel driver: sof-audio-pci 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.10.0-1013-oem 
Network:   Device-1: Intel Wireless-AC 9462 driver: iwlwifi 
           IF: wlp0s20f3 state: up mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-1: br-a21b1df0c1df state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: unknown mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-2: br-befa31479b4a state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: unknown mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-3: docker0 state: down mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-4: veth027c5d0 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-5: veth0355457 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-6: veth1ccac4d state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-7: veth28ec2cb state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-8: veth6ce2dd0 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-9: vethb4ed242 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-10: vethc5c43f3 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-11: vethc6fa7ea state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-12: vethe48e562 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 50.45 GiB (10.6%) 
           ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: SK Hynix model: PC601 HFS512GD9TNG-L2A0A size: 476.94 GiB 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 467.03 GiB used: 24.97 GiB (5.3%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/dm-0 
           ID-2: /boot size: 944.6 MiB used: 511.9 MiB (54.2%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 57.0 C mobo: 45.0 C 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Repos:     No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list 
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list 
           1: deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list 
           1: deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-stella.cmit-charizard-meta.list 
           1: deb http://hp.archive.canonical.com/ focal stella
           2: deb http://hp.archive.canonical.com/ focal stella.cmit
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list 
           1: deb http://packages.linuxmint.com ulyssa main upstream import backport
           2: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted universe multiverse
           3: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
           4: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
           5: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
           6: deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ focal partner
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-php-focal.list 
           1: deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal main
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list 
           1: deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.skype.com/deb stable main
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/slack.list 
           1: deb https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian/ jessie main
Info:      Processes: 336 Uptime: 9m Memory: 30.71 GiB used: 2.04 GiB (6.6%) Shell: bash inxi: 3.0.38
```